# Selecting unique rows and copying their values as tranpose

Tags: excel, transpose, vba

I am trying to select unique rows and copying their values as transpose in diff sheet.

I meaning making the VBA code dynamic.

Here is an example

```
Raw Excel
x 1
x 2 
x 3
y 4
y 5
z 6

Desired output
x  y  z
1  4  6
2  5
3
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Sub a()
DataRow = 1
DataCol = 1
OutputRow = 1
OutputCol = 4

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
OutputCol = OutputCol - 1
While Cells(DataRow, DataCol).Value <> 0
    Cells(DataRow, DataCol).Select
    ThisValue = Cells(DataRow, DataCol).Value
    If ThisValue <> PrevValue Then
        OutputCol = OutputCol + 1
        MyRow = OutputRow
        Cells(MyRow, OutputCol).Value = Cells(DataRow, DataCol).Value
        MyRow = OutputRow + 1
    End If
    Cells(MyRow, OutputCol).Value = Cells(DataRow, DataCol + 1).Value
    PrevValue = ThisValue
    DataRow = DataRow + 1
    MyRow = MyRow + 1
Wend
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```